# How can i power on a pc from keyboard on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: shortcut-keys

How can i power on a pc from keyboard on ubuntu 14.04 ?

I'm using ubuntu 14.04, anyone help me about that....

Comment: I don't think that's possible, and the OS you're using won't affect it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your PC is a PowerMac/iMac/etc…, or your BIOS and keyboard both have some way to do this, then you cannot. It has nothing to do with Ubuntu.